# Añadir tres intentos validación de contraseña JavaScript

Tags: javascript

estoy con un ejercicio de JS donde me piden meter una contraseña con un requisitos y que si al tercer intento la meta mal, no puedas seguir metiendo datos en el input. El problema es que lo tengo con validación al tiempo real, el cual hasta que no metes la palabra bien, es invalido siempre. Dejo mi código.

```
document
    .getElementById('campo')
    .addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
        const campo = evt.target,
            valido = document.getElementById('campoOK'),

            regex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$%*&\-\_])[A-Za-z\d$@$%*&\-\_]{8,16}$/;

        if (regex.test(campo.value)) {
            valido.innerText = "válido";

        } else {
            valido.innerText = "incorrecto";

        }
    });
```

Comment: Qués es lo que validas con esa Regex?

Comment: que al menos tenga un numero, una mayus otra minus, un caracter especial y que este en el rango entre 8 y 16 letras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con un `button` para validar la contraseña, agregando un contador sabremos cuántos intentos lleva, al tercer intento erróneo el botón de `validar` se bloqueará.

```js
document.getElementById('validar').addEventListener('click', valida);

let contador = 1;
function valida(){

        const campo = document.getElementById('campo');
            valido = document.getElementById('campoOK'),

            regex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$%*&\-\_])[A-Za-z\d$@$%*&\-\_]{8,16}$/;

        if (regex.test(campo.value)) {
            valido.innerHTML = "válido";

        } else {
            valido.innerHTML = "incorrecto";
            console.log(`Intento: ${contador}`);
            if(contador === 3){
              document.getElementById('validar').disabled = 'true';
            }
            contador++;
        }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="campo">
<button id="validar">Validar</button>
<div id="campoOK"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Un gusto mi estimado! :)

Answer (score 1):

Agregando un listener al evento `input` lo que haces es evaluar cada vez que hay un cambio en dicho campo, en este caso cada tecla que se presiona.

Osea que si el texto parcial que está escribiendo no valida, se va a contar como incorrecto. Como en tu regex el mínimo es 8 caracteres, siempre va a dar inválido en la tercer tecla que presionemos, cualquiera sea.

Además de eso, el contador debería estar fuera, para no reiniciar el contador en cada evento.
Para hacer mas cómodo el testeo, en la regex pongo por bueno solo si ingresan números.

```js
let intentos = 0;

document
  .getElementById('validar')
  .addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    const campo = document.getElementById('campo'),
      valido = document.getElementById('campoOK')


    if (intentos >= 3) {
      return;
    }

    if (/^\d+$/g.test(campo.value)) {
      valido.innerText = "válido";
      intentos = 0;

    } else {
      intentos++;
      valido.innerText = "incorrecto, intentos: " + intentos;

      if (intentos >= 3) {
        valido.innerText = "Nunca mas vas a poder intentar";
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<input id="campo" type="text"><button id="validar">validar</button>
<div id="campoOK"></div>

</div>
```